# What do the labels (such as <*dircheck>) mean in `source2e.pdf`?

Tags: package-writing, latex-base, dtx

I am studying `source2e.pdf` and I have encountered something such as `<*dircheck>`, `<*initex>`, `<*2ekernel>`,`<latexrelease>`. I thought that they might be some sort of label to mark different parts of the LaTeX source - `*` probably means the beginning of a part and `/` probably means the end of a part. But as I continued to read they just didn't make much sense to me. And I didn't find anything that explains the use of these labels in `source2e.pdf`. The document just goes directly to the various `.dtx` files after the contents, without any explanation of the notation used in the document.

(I don't know what tags are suitable for this question, so I just chose a tag randomly. Someone else might choose a more appropriate tag.)

Comment: These are docstrip guards: https://www.texdev.net/2009/10/05/the-dtx-format/ and https://www.texdev.net/2009/10/06/a-model-dtx-file/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are docstrip guards as moewe commented, you will see `.ins` files in that directory that control which guards are used when building each file.

Of the ones you mentioned:

`dircheck` code is used very early in the latex format unpacking to check the directory syntax, now all systems use `/` even windows, but originally we had to support VMS, flat mainframe file systems with no directory structure at all, filesystems with no extensions so `article.sty` was mapped to `article` in a subdirectory `sty` etc...

`initex` marks a block of code that is just used to when using `initex` for format creation

`2ekernel` is the bulk of the latex sources, that get extracted into `latex.ltx`

`latexrelese` marks old versions of the code that do not go into `latex.ltx` but are instead extracted into `latexrelease.sty` to allow rollback to previous versions.

The detailed syntax of these guards is described in the LaTeX Companion book, or more directly in the `docstrip` documentation (`texdoc docstrip` in texlive).